# How to get previous block time using timestamp

Tags: substrate-node-template, timestamp

How I can get the **previous block** time using timestamp pallet

Answer (score 2):

To start off, when using polkadot.js the current time can be retrieved via:

```typescript
api.query.timestamp.now()
```

Under the hood, this uses the `state` collection of RPC methods (`state_getStorage`, `state_subscribeStorage`, etc).

These methods take two parameters, a `storage key` and a `blockhash`.

The `storage key` is [the encoded format](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/transparent-keys-in-substrate/) of the key for the storage you want to query.

The block hash is optional, and if omitted the query will default to the current block.

---

So first we need to fetch the `blockhash` of the block you want to query, i.e. `the previous block`:

```typescript
// get the latest block number
const blockNumber = await api.query.system.number()

// determine the previous block number
const previousBlockNumber = blockNumber.subn(1)

// fetch the previous block hash
const previousBlockHash = await api.query.system.blockHash(previousBlockNumber)
```

Then we need to pass this `blockhash` to the `timestamp.now` query:

```typescript
api.query.timestamp.now.at(previousBlockHash)
```